# Retrieve function parameter from parent function

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, scope

I have a function call in my script that contain a callback function call on a fadeOut call. I'm trying to pass the paren't function parameter into the callback function, but I can't seem to get it working.

The general script structure is:

```
function aFunction(aVar){
    anElement.fadeOut(200, function(){
        someFunctionCall(aVar);
    });
}
```

The call is performed correctly, but the variable is not passed. It's probably a scoping issue on the variable but I don't quite understand the concept here.

Comment: That should work. Have you tried `console.log(aVar)` both inside `aFunction`, fadeOuts's callback and `someFunctionCall`?

Comment: I second that.  Your code is correct.

Comment: ok will try logging my code to see what is going. I'll let you know.

Comment: @user751564 - eicto produced this fiddle demonstrating the correctness of your code and posted as a comment to my answer.  Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/fXRbh/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code

```
function aFunction(aVar){
    anElement.fadeOut(200, function(){
        someFunctionCall(aVar);
    });
}
```

is correct as written.  Your inner function, and any other functions you declare, **automatically** have access to all variables in the containing scope.  The function you're passing to fadeOut will form a **closure** over aVar, and continue to have access to it even after aFunction has long since returned.

Comment: just to confirm, 
http://jsfiddle.net/fXRbh/

It works as writen @user751564 search other problem

Comment: http://paste.debian.net/1002532/
In there should not the `data` param of the anonymous function be available inside the `formDisplayGrid` function without passing it as a param?Please comment.
`callService` is an ajax call making function which gets the anonymous function in its `success` callback.

Answer (score -1):

You could store it in a local variable:

```
function aFunction(aVar){
    var new_var = aVar;
    anElement.fadeOut(200, function(){
             someFunctionCall(new_var);
     });
}
```